# How to split and join specific letters of a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, join, split

I am a newbie in Python and ran into something I thought it is easy.

Let's say, I have strings with two letters, `'al'` in random positions, e.g.:

```
original_words = "installation alcohol international"
```

How can I split the original_words into letters but at the same time join letters `"a"` and `"l"`?

**The output I would like to achieve**:

```
['i', 'n', 's', 't', 'al', 'l', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'al', 'c', 'o', 'h', 'o', 'l', 'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'al']
```

Thanks, a lot.

Comment: Simplest way would probably be to make a list of single letters, then iterate over the list and join consecutive a's and l's together.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with a loop to go through the letters. It looks like the output you provided has ['al', 'c', 'o', 'h', 'o', 'l'] instead of ['al', 't', 'i', 't', 'u', 'd', 'e']. But this method should work for any input string, as long as 'al' are the only letters you want to group every time.

```
original_words = "installation altitude international"
split_words = []
indx = 0

while indx in range(len(original_words)):
    # Check if letter grouping is "al"
    if original_words[indx] + original_words[indx+1] == 'al':
        # Append "al" and skip 2 indicies
        split_words.append(original_words[indx] + original_words[indx+1])
        indx += 2
    else:
        # Otherwise, append letter and skip 1 index
        split_words.append(original_words[indx])
        indx += 1
print(split_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
original_words = "installation altitude international"

# removing the spaces between the words.!
t=original_words.replace(" ","")

# created a temporary string in which 'al' is replaced by '^' you can replace with any character/word which is not in the original_words
temp_str = t.replace("al", "^")

# converted into a list
letters_list = list(temp_str)

#List comprehension [replace the '^' to al]
res = [x.replace("^", "al") for x in letters_list]

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['i', 'n', 's', 't', 'al', 'l', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'al', 't', 'i', 't', 'u', 'd', 'e', 'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'al']
```

I think the desired output you want is this. let me know if this is not your desired output.

Comment: Op's just changing `original_words` to `installation altitude international` and `installation alcohol international` that's why my output list contains `c` .. anyway my bad!! thank you to notify me :) @GauravHazra

Answer (score 0):

I thing the simplest way would be to [`split`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/split) by "al" before collecting all letters:

```py
keep_substring = 'al'
keep_whitespace = False # set True to keep spaces, newline characters, etc
original_words = "installation altitude international"

opList = []
for ss in original_words.split('al'):
    if opList: opList.append(keep_substring)
    opList += [c for c in ss if c.strip() or keep_whitespace]
print(opList)
```

After the loop, `opList` should be as you wanted the output to be

> ```py
> ['i', 'n', 's', 't', 'al', 'l', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'al', 't', 'i', 't', 'u', 'd', 'e', 'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'al']
> ```

But if you set `keep_whitespace = True`, the spaces will also be included in `opList`

> ```py
> ['i', 'n', 's', 't', 'al', 'l', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', ' ', 'al', 't', 'i', 't', 'u', 'd', 'e', ' ', 'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'al']
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
original_words = "installation altitude international".replace(" ", "")
original_words_split = original_words.split("al")
print(original_words_split)
new_list =[]

for split_word in original_words_split:
    if(""!=split_word):
        new_list.extend(list(split_word.strip()))
        new_list.append("al")


print( new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a comma between every character then remove the ones between "a" and "l" and split again on commas:

```
",".join(original_words).replace("a,l","al").split(",")

['i', 'n', 's', 't', 'al', 'l', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', ' ', 'al', 'c',
 'o', 'h', 'o', 'l', ' ', 'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', 't', 'i',
 'o', 'n', 'al']
```

*You can use something other than a comma as a separator (e.g. "\n") if the string may already contain commas*

If you want to remove spaces, you should do it on the resulting list (after the split) otherwise you could end up getting "al" when a word ending in "a" is followed by a word starting with "l"  (e.g: "data log")

Answer (score 0):

With `list` you can split the string into single characters. Then you can loop over the list, compare two consecutive characters and if they are "a" and "l" you replace the first one with "al" and remove the second element.

```
original_words = "installation alcohol international"

l = list(original_words)

for i in range(len(l) - 1, -1, -1):
    if l[i] == 'a' and l[i + 1] == 'l':
        l[i] = 'al'
        del l[i + 1]

print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not opposed to using a module from the standard library, you could use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/re.html#module-re) and do:

```py
import re

result = re.findall("al|\S", original_words)
```

```py
['i', 'n', 's', 't', 'al', 'l', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'al', 'c', 'o', 'h', 'o',
 'l', 'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'al']
```

If you want to keep the whitespace:

```py
result = re.findall("al|.", original_words)
```

```py
['i', 'n', 's', 't', 'al', 'l', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', ' ', 'al', 'c', 'o', 'h', 'o',
 'l', ' ', 'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'al']
```